# Python .. What is this syntax with colon in a particular statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

What is use of the colon in the sample below? ...the one with the FloatProperty

At this link
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_overview.html

there is a code sample

```
class MyMaterialSubProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    my_float: bpy.props.FloatProperty() 
    # ... is it a dunder?  type declaration for language tools?
```

Comment: That's a type hint. See also the relevant [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) for a description of the syntax.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-variable-annotation

Comment: @N.Wouda Thanks.  So No memory is allocated at that point?

Comment: @wwii Thanks for the link.  Of course you two gave immediate answers but ... what should I have searched seeing only the syntax above?  Low priority question.  I saw the class and foreach and if use of (colon)